# CS50 Pset2. Vigenere. Upper text to lower key and vice versa problems

Tags: c, vigenere, cs50

Okay. So, I need to make a Vigenere cypher. When the text and key are both upper case of both lower case, the code compiles fine. But when the text and the key differ from case, the code is not working. Then it doesn't print anything. For example when the key is: aaAA. And the text is aBcD. The outcome is: aD. Can someone give me a hint, please? :)

```c
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (int argc, string argv[])
{
    string key = argv [1]; //argv [1] is the key. 0 is compile program
{    
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf ("Please give one key: "); //if there are more or less then 2 argc, then have to try again
    }

for (int j = 0, n = strlen (key); j < n; j++)
    if (!isalpha (key [j]))      
    {
        printf ("Please give a key in alphabetic characters: ");
        //key must be alphabetic. For loop to check every character of the key. 
        return 1;
    }
}

string text = GetString(); //Get secret message from user

int j = 0;
for (int i = 0, n = strlen (text); i < n; i++)
{
    if (isupper (text [i]))
    {
        if (isupper (key [j]))
        {
        /*Minus 65 to make count till 26 from text and key. Use modulo to wrap around key. And modulo to wrap around alphabet.
        Plus 65 to go to correct ASCII character. */
        int u = ((((text [i] - 65) + (key [j % strlen (key)] - 65)) % 26) + 65);
        printf ("%c", u);
        }
    }
    else if (islower (text [i]))
     {
        if (islower (key[j]))
        {
        int l = ((((text [i] - 97) + (key [j % strlen (key)] - 97)) % 26) + 97);
        printf ("%c", l);
        }
    }
    else if (islower (text [i]))
    {  
        if (isupper (key[j]))
        {
        int lu = ((((text [i] - 97) + (key [j % strlen (key)] - 65)) % 26) + 97);
        printf ("%c", lu);
        }
    }
    else if (isupper (text [i]))
    {
        if (islower (key[j]))
        {
        int ul = ((((text [i] - 65 + (key [j % strlen (key)] - 97)) % 26) + 65);
        printf ("%c", ul);
        }
    }
    else
        {
        // When character is non alphabetic print it in its original form.
        printf ("%c", text [i]);
        }
    j++; 
}
{
    printf ("\n");
    return 0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your if, else-if, else-if... statements. The reason is cause `if isupper(text[i])` returns true, and `if isupper(key[j])` returns false it will never evaluate the else if statements. You should do this

```
if( isupper(text[i])){
    if(isupper(key[j])){ // Both upper
       //do stuff
    }
    else if(islower(key[j])){ //Here key is lower and text is upper
       //do stuff
    }
}
else if (islower(text[i])){
    if (islower(key[j])){ //Both lower
        //do stuff
    }
    else if(isupper(key[j])){ //Key upper and text lower
        //do stuff
    }
}
else{//It's not alpha
    //do stuff
}

/***************NEW********************/
j = j%strlen(key); //I suggest using this at the end of the loop to avoid key[j] to go out of it's bounds
// j = (j==strlen(key)) ? 0 : j; //Another alternative
```

Also, I think you shouldn't be increasing `j` if the character is not alpha

Comment: Okay, thanks so much. Now the upper-lower key is working correctly. But it doesn't wrap around the key. The code works fine the first time. But when the text is longer it doesn't wrap around properly. can't seem to make it work . Any suggestions?

Comment: @Kim Sorry, the problem is in the `if` statements for the key. You should use `key[j%strlen(key)]` or you would go out of it's bounds. I'll update answer

Comment: Ahaa, I understand. Thanks so much for your help. Finally finished it :)